# php "script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object" error

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I have looked up this error, and it seems the common issue is caused by not putting include()'s or require()'s BEFORE session_start().

However, this is not the case for me.

I am getting the following error:

Fatal error: Zend_Http_Client::request() [zend-http-client.request]: The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition in /home/content/*/*/*/*****/html/ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library/Zend/Http/Client.php on line 865

Any idea why?

Here are the three relevant files: login.php, members.php, and functions.php...

login.php:

```
 $newIncludePath = array();
 $newIncludePath[] = '../ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library';
 $newIncludePath = implode($newIncludePath);
 set_include_path($newIncludePath);

 // load classes
 require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');

 session_start();


 $serviceName = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; // predefined service name ('cl') for calendar
 $applicationName = 'yourCompany-yourAppName-v1';

 // Create an authenticated HTTP client
 $httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('*****@gmail.com', '*****', $serviceName, null, $applicationName);
 $client = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($httpClient, $applicationName); // Create an instance of the Calendar service

 $_SESSION['gdataCal'] = $client;
```

members.php:

```
 $newIncludePath = array();
 $newIncludePath[] = '../ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library';
 $newIncludePath = implode($newIncludePath);
 set_include_path($newIncludePath);

 // load classes
 require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');

 session_start();

 $g_url = add_gcal($_SESSION['gdataCal'], $_SESSION['title'].....etc.);
```

functions.php:

```
 <?php

 $newIncludePath = array();
 $newIncludePath[] = '../ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library';
 $newIncludePath = implode($newIncludePath);
 set_include_path($newIncludePath);

 // load classes
 require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');
 Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

session_start();

function add_gcal($gdataCal, $title....etc.){

try {

    $newEvent = $gdataCal->newEventEntry();

    $newEvent->title = $gdataCal->newTitle($title);
    $newEvent->where = array($gdataCal->newWhere($where));
    $newEvent->content = $gdataCal->newContent("$desc");

    $when = $gdataCal->newWhen();
    $when->startTime = $date;
    $when->endTime = $date; 
    $newEvent->when = array($when);

    $createdEvent = $gdataCal->insertEvent($newEvent);
    return $createdEvent->id->text;

  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        return NULL;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this message :

> Please ensure that the class
>   definition
>   "`Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket`" of
>   the object you are trying to operate
>   on was loaded before unserialize()
>   gets called

So, I suppose you have something in session (which means store in a serialized form) that is an instance of `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket`

So, before the `session_start`, you should load that class, using, for instance, something like this :

```
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket');
```

This should solve **this** problem... But, as Zend Framework has lots of classes that rely on each others, you might run into another one...

A way to get rid of those errors for ever would be to use Zend Framework's autoloader : instead of locading classes yourself with `Zend_Loader::loadClass`, you could just register/activate the autoloader, and it will automatically load classes for you, whenever they are needed.

Of couse, that too would have to be done before the call to `session_start` **:-)**

For more informations about ZF's autoloader, you can take a look at [this page of the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html).

Comment: I've discovered that even changing `$_SESSION` (without explicitly calling `session_start()`) before loading the class will cause this behavior.